# MediaRecorder Crash?

Tags: android, opencv

I am going to record video but it's not working

```
public void startRecord() {
    if (preVideo()) {
        mRecorder.start();
    }
    isRecording = true;
}

public boolean preVideo() {
    if (mCamera == null) {
        return false;
    }

    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);

    CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    mRecorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(createFile().toString());
    mRecorder.setVideoSize(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);

    return true;
}
```

and logcat;

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: pt.chambino.p.pulse, PID: 6578
>                                                                      java.lang.IllegalStateException
>                                                                          at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
>                                                                          at org.opencv.android.MyJavaCameraView.startRecord(MyJavaCameraView.java:375)
>                                                                          at pt.chambino.p.pulse.App.onRecord(App.java:241)
>                                                                          at pt.chambino.p.pulse.App.onOptionsItemSelected(App.java:213)
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2600)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:1019)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:546)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:119)
>                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4569)
>                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18553)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5151)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
>                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Hi, ADM. thanks for  your reply.

Comment: What if you add `mRecorder.prepare();` before `return true;` in `preVideo()`?

Comment: mRecorder.start();

Comment: it also crashed.

Comment: Was it a different error when you called `mRecorder.prepare()`?

Comment: no differences.

Comment: Refer to the diagram [in this documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) - are you following all the correct methods in the correct order? Looks like you're also missing `setOutputFormat()` immediately after `setVideoSource()`

Comment: crashed here.  mRecorder.start();

Comment: I know that it's crashed there. `mRecorder.start()` **will** crash unless you complete **all** of the preparatory steps beforehand.

Comment: also crashed after add setOutputFormat();

Comment: How do you think about mCamera.unlock(); mRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

Comment: Can you post your updated code with everything you've tried since?

Comment: can we discuss via skype?

Comment: I'd rather keep everything on StackOverflow as this question may help others in the future.

Comment: I see you're using `Recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);` - Shouldn't this be `VideoSource.CAMERA` instead?

Comment: just a sec. I'll push my project to the github.

Comment: Also, what's going on with `mCamera`? Are you directly opening it elsewhere as that's the only other way you can get an `IllegalStateException` with `start()`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can trigger an `IllegalStateException` with [`MediaRecorder.start()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#start()):

- The recording input you're using is already in use
- You've not prepared the `MediaRecorder` properly for recording.

Consider this state diagram from [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html):

[image]

Discounting the first option as there's not enough information to confirm or deny it, if I were to compare the flow of your code, it looks like you're missing two steps:

- `setOutputFormat`
- `prepare`

You also have the video source set as your phone's screen rather than the camera, so I would change your code to be like this:

```
public void startRecord() {
    try {
        if (preVideo()) {
            mRecorder.start();
            isRecording = true;
        }
    } catch(IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Error handling
    }
}

public boolean preVideo() throws IllegalStateException, IOException {
    if (mCamera == null) {
        return false;
    }

    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

    CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    mRecorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(createFile().toString());
    mRecorder.setVideoSize(mFrameWidth, mFrameHeight);

    mRecorder.prepare();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167494/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-dodd-mediarecorder-crash).

Comment: The problem is that OP assumes that `CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH)` is available.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace:**

```
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

**With this:**

```
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
```